# Adventages of Docker as development envioroment

Tags: linux, mysql, docker, apache2

I have my dev server with bit older PHP version. However sometimes i need newer versions of PHP or MySQL for certian projects, sometimes older.

I'm considering setting up a Docker server, but I'm not sure how it would work out.

My main goal would be to host few different servers on one machine. Would docker allow me to do such a thing?

Currently i have one server and end up reinstalling XAMPP on my local machine for some projects.

What I would like to achive: One machine, few servers on it without VM. And each server would have its own domain. Would docker be a good solution for such setup? (if its possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use docker to achieve what you want. You can run different copies of the php container ( different versions of php ).

They expose ports, so you probably will have to route the port 80/port 443 to the correct docker container.

Make sure you read a bit about the differences between docker and a VM that will set some expectations right.